# How to use common table expression to filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Would anyone be willing to point me in the right direction? I am using the AdventureWorks2012 database to work through some training and I  am not quite sure how to solve a problem where I need find all of the Purchase Orders (SalesOrderHeader) that do not use the shipping method of "OVERSEAS -DELUXE" or "OVERNIGHT J-FAST" (ShipMethod) and I have to do this using a common table expression.

Here is what I have come up with so far, which is seems to be incorrect:

```
 WITH filteredshipmethods (ShipMethodID, Name, PurchaseOrderNumber)
    as 
    (SELECT Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.ShipMethodID, Purchasing.ShipMethod.Name, Sales.SalesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber
FROM     Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader INNER JOIN
                  Purchasing.ShipMethod ON Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.ShipMethodID = Purchasing.ShipMethod.ShipMethodID INNER JOIN
                  Sales.SalesOrderHeader ON Purchasing.ShipMethod.ShipMethodID = Sales.SalesOrderHeader.ShipMethodID
WHERE   Purchasing.ShipMethod.Name <> 'OVERSEAS - DELUXE' AND Purchasing.ShipMethod.Name <> 'OVERNIGHT J-FAST' And PurchaseOrderNumber is not null)
    SELECT PurchaseOrderNumber, ShipMethodID, Name
    From filteredshipmethods
    Group By ShipMethodID, Name, PurchaseOrderNumber
    Order By Name;
```

Comment: what is the issue with this SQL? Please post the error or issues

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output. I am only getting back one shippingmethod which must mean my and/or is incorrect?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3AViuv_IDu2ejJiRm0wdnNxbWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You really dont need a common table expression there.... its pretty stright forward select query you have....

Answer (score 0):

If the task is just find SalesOrderHeaders then why are you joining on PurchaseOrderHeader? And please use aliases, it will help you to minimize code and better understand what you have.try:

```
WITH    filteredshipmethods
          AS ( SELECT   soh.PurchaseOrderNumber ,
                        sm.ShipMethodID ,
                        sm.Name
               FROM     Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
                        INNER JOIN Purchasing.ShipMethod sm ON soh.ShipMethodID = sm.ShipMethodID
               WHERE    sm.Name <> 'OVERSEAS - DELUXE'
                        AND sm.Name <> 'OVERNIGHT J-FAST'
             )
    SELECT  PurchaseOrderNumber ,
            ShipMethodID ,
            Name
    FROM    filteredshipmethods
    GROUP BY PurchaseOrderNumber ,
            ShipMethodID ,
            Name
```

Comment: The query as it stands only returns back the Purchase Orders with ShipMethodID of 5; there are a total of 5 different methods (ID's). I should be seeing all of the purchase orders with the excetion of the Purchase Orders that Have a shipping method of 3 and 4.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3AViuv_IDu2NFF1U2R5QVlMZ2s/edit

Comment: There is Method 1, scroll down. Method 2 is not present in table SalesOrderHeader

Comment: Only problem is. If I run a query on the Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader and filter out shipmethodID of 3 &4; I get lots of PurchaseOrderID's with all of the other shipMethodID's which don't seem to exist in my query.

Comment: Don't join PurchaseOrderHeader and SalesOrderHeader by ShipMethod. its nonsense

Comment: hmm... from what I can see, I can only get the PurchaseOrderNumber from the SalesOrderHeader

Comment: The question is why you are joining on PurchaseOrderHeader?